# Problem with trying to encrypt .txts files in python

Tags: python-3.x

Ok so I made this simple encryption program (I am new to python) that encrypts every file in the directory it is being used (For learning purposes).
Here's the code:

```
import os
import time
txts = list()
for i in os.listdir():
    if i.endswith('.txt'):
        txts.append(i)    
for i in txts:
    filer = open(i, 'r')
    st = str()
    for j in filer.read():
        st += chr(ord(j)+2)
    filew = open(i,'w')
    filew.write(st)
    
def decrypt():
    for i in txts:
        filer = open(i, 'r')
        st = str()
        for j in filer.read():
            st += chr(ord(j)-2)
        filew = open(i,'w')
        filew.write(st)
```

So my problem is: It encrypts every single file txt file in the directory, besides the last one, always. The last file always gets overwritten with nothing, unlike all the others, no matter what txt is the last file. Ive checked the txts list and All the txt files in the directory. But the last file, just doesnt want to get encrypted. Lets say I put abcd in the file, after my program runs in the file there won't be a single thing.

Comment: Have you tried closing the 'opened' file cleanly? For example, add 'filew.close()' at the end of writing to each of it in the loop.

Comment: yes, I did use close, but I was still running into this issue. I solved by putting in a function and then calling, but still don't know what the problem was before

Comment: Seems to be environment issue: original code works fine for me. I'm using `Python 3.9.5` on `WSL Ubuntu 20.04.3`

Answer (score 0):

When you put the "encryption" code in a function, the file objects returned by `open` go out of scope and are garbage collected. Part of that process for file objects is flushing write buffers and closing the files.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> **Warning:** Calling `f.write()` without using the `with` keyword or calling `f.close()` **might** result in the arguments of `f.write()` not being completely written to the disk, even if the program exits successfully.